# ASP.NET validation happens on postback

Tags: asp.net, validation, postback

I have a form with some input controls on a standard ASP.NET page. I use validation controls to validate the input on the server.

I noticed there are a few articles describing problems with the fact that postbacks are prevented when validation fails. My problem is kind of the opposite, i.e. postbacks are never prevented, but validation happens every time a postback occurs meaning that the form is painted over with red text every time the user changes a value in an input field (even though he is well aware that he didn't complete the form!).

Other articles at this forum argue that this behaviour is intended. Obviously the user don't want to be bothered about information telling him that he did something wrong before he pressed 'Submit' sow how do I configure the controls to only show the validation summary when the submit button is pressed and not on any postback?

Note: I only call Page.IsValid when the submit button is pressed - no where else. Thanks.

Comment: can you show the asp page you are trying to validate also make sure the button is set true on cause validation

Comment: *Misconception* here - read ASP.NET [Page-lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) [Validating User Input in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542.aspx) - Validation occurs after page initialization (that is, after view state and postback data have been processed) but before any change or click event handlers are called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding validationgroup property to all of your validators and a button you want to cause validation. see more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx
Example:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Runat="server" ValidationGroup="First"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" Runat="server" ValidationGroup="First"
    ErrorMessage="TextBox1 should not be blank" ControlToValidate="TextBox1">

    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="Submit1" Runat="server" ValidationGroup="First" Text="Submit 1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply give the **same** validation group property for all the controls you need to validate on button click. Also your button must have the same validation group and set the **causevalidation** property of button to true.
This should avoid you from postback.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Validation groups are to localize the ValidationSummary display area, typically to be physically close to their associated data-fields.
Has nothing to do with auto-postback on value change.

I'd check to see if client scripting is enabled on your validators.
If not, only the server could validate the data - requiring a post-back on any value change.

PS: on simple forms, I never use validation groups as all reported errors can be accumulated under the default group and associated messages displayed together.
On complex forms, I may create several groups to have the errors physically close to the offending data.  Regardless of your grouping, *ALL* validation methods will run - and report to the associated validationSummary within the designated group, if supplied.
**EDIT**
this from Microsoft:

> To validate programmatically, you can call the Validate method
>   overload that takes the validationGroup parameter to force validation
>   for only that validation group. Note that when you call the Validate
>   method, the IsValid property reflects the validity of all groups
>   validated so far. This could include both a group that was validated
>   as a result of a postback, and the programmatically validated group.
>   If any control in either group is invalid, the IsValid property
>   returns false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227424(v=vs.100).aspx

the GROUPS have nothing to do with post-back.  He probably has a control(s) with auto-postback set, or scripting turned off.